# Cómo solucionar: AssertionError: 404 != 200 Django DRF

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework, testing

estoy haciendo un test para un RetrieveUpdateAPIView.
Me falla el primer test y la verdad que no se porqué:

urls.py: (Las pruebas son para el segundo caso)
[image: Urls.py]

test.py

[image: test.py]

Para crear una nueva cuenta utilizo las factorías existentes y le meto el uuid creado.
Para comprobar que esto funcionaba:

[image: make shell]

Por último el error:

[image: terminal > pytest]

No se si es que no guarda bien los datos..
Se os ocurre algo?

Gracias por adelantado ^^

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon el código y los mensajes de error _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido solucionar el problema. Lo publico por si algún día le es de ayuda a alguien:

Lo único que había que hacer era especificar el usuario logado en la factoría que estaba creando la cuenta:
account = AccountFactory(user=self.user)

Con eso he conseguido que se solucionara el problema de assertionEqual.

Comment: De nuevo, no olvides colocar el código _como texto, con formato_ (ya que mostrar código como imagen [es mala idea](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976)) y de [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta. Una vez más, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.